# How to set systemd service dependencies?

Tags: centos, nginx, boot, service, systemd

During CentOS 7 system boot nginx start fails with the following error:

```
2014/08/04 17:27:34 [emerg] 790#0: bind() to a.b.c.d:443 failed (99: Cannot assign requested address)
```

I suspect this is happening due to the network interfaces not being up yet before attempting to bind to that IP address for serving a vhost over SSL.

My guess is I need to specify the network.service as a requirement for the nginx.service, but I can't find the network service in /etc/systemd/ at all.

**How can I configure the service order or dependencies in systemd?**

Comment: Aren't you looking more for service *dependencies* than *order*?

Comment: Good point! Updated.

Comment: This may help: http://serverfault.com/questions/482730/systemd-dependencies-and-boot-order

Comment: Thanks, that solves it! Mind to put it in an answer so I can close it? :)

Comment: Deleted my answer. Source of that answer posted (Mr. Hampton). Should mark his as the correct answer.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need, at minimum, `After=network.target` in the `[Unit]` section of your unit file, to ensure that the network is up before starting nginx. I have no idea why your unit file doesn't have it.

Here is a complete example from my handy Fedora system, as shipped by Fedora:

```
[Unit]
Description=The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server
After=syslog.target network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/run/nginx.pid
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
ExecStop=/bin/kill -s QUIT $MAINPID
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Thanks, great answer! I installed nginx from the remi repository (third-party), which might explain why "After" is missing in the unit file.

Comment: Interesting. I would drop him a note and let him know about the problem. His packages are usually very high quality and I'm not sure how he missed that.

Comment: Great suggestion, done.

Answer (score 10):

From the error log, it looks like your nginx config. file has a listen directive with an explicit ip address:

```
listen a.b.c.d:443
```

This means that nginx won't start unless your network interface is up *and* the IP a.b.c.d has been assigned to the interface.

You have two options:

- change the listen directive to: listen 443; (bind to all ip addresses)
- make nginx depend on network-online.target

As described in http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget/ the network.target *only indicates that the network management stack is up [...] Whether any network interfaces are already configured when it is reached is undefined.*

If you want to make sure that the IP address is already assigned and the interface is up, you need to add the network-online.target to your nginx's systemd unit file.

Your /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/nginx.service file should have network-online.target in the After= and Requires= lines.

```
[Unit]
Description=The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server
After=syslog.target network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target network-online.target
Requires=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/run/nginx.pid
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
ExecStop=/bin/kill -s QUIT $MAINPID
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning `network-online.target` - in case somebody is also wondering: yes, both `Requires=` and `After=` are necessary because `Requires=` (arguably surprisingly) doesn't imply an ordering between the required unit and the requiring one.