# Support Multiple Service Dependencies in Requires Directive in RedHat 8.9

Tags: redhat, systemd, systemctl

Thank You for looking into the question.

I have a Systemd service lets call it main-application.service which needs service testA.service and testB.service started before start of itself.
Following is the service implementation(dir location - /usr/lib/systemd/system)

main-application.service file

```
[Unit]
Description=Main App
After=testA.service
After=testB.service
Requires=testA.service testB.service

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/appl/main-application/env-1.conf
EnvironmentFile=/appl/main-application/env-2.conf
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar $EXEC_PATH --spring.config.location=file:/appl/main-application/app.properties
User=root
SuccessExitStatus=143

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

testA.service

```
[Unit]
Description=SVC A
After=syslog.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/appl/service-a/main.sh
User=root

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

testB.service

```
[Unit]
Description=SVC B
After=syslog.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/appl/service-b/main.sh
User=root

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

We want test service A and B both to execute before main application service, there is no ordering requirement. I have still specified "After" directive in main service in the hope that it might work but it doesnot.
Weird thing is when I restart main application service it randomly starts either test service A or B but not both.

OS - Redhat 8.9

Can you give suggestions? Thank You in Advance !!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set systemd service dependencies?](https://serverfault.com/questions/617823/how-to-set-systemd-service-dependencies)

Comment: @RomeoNinov Actually I already tried adding After directive with or without Requires directive however it doesn't enforce the depencies to start always beforehand. Same is suggested in above link.