# Docker service starts before ZFS

Tags: ubuntu, docker, zfs, ubuntu-16.04, zfsonlinux

I am using Docker CE on Ubuntu 16.04, with ZFS as storage for Docker. Setup is pretty much standard:

1. There's a zpool that has multiple disks
2. On the zpool, there's a zfs filesystem with mountpoint `/var/lib/docker`.
3. Docker sees that the filesystem is ZFS, and uses that automatically

Everything works most of the time. However, once in a while when my VM boots up, the zpool fails to mount. I believe (though I am not 100% sure) that this is because the Docker service starts before the ZFS filesystem is mounted, and in fact I see a `/var/lib/docker` folder created on the root FS.

How can I ensure that the Docker service does not start until all ZFS filesystems are mounted?

Comment: Depending on the details, you could try to add `[Unit] Requires=zfs.target` to the docker service using `systemctl edit docker`. Where you need a newline between `[Unit]` and `Requires=`. Don't know how to reflect that in a comment.

Comment: @Thomas I hear your point. Is waiting for `zfs.target` an assurance that all the filesystems will be mounted? Rather than `Requires=`, however, shouldn't I use `After=`? And rather than editing a unit file, I should add another one that does nothing but says `Before=docker.service` and `After=zfs.target.`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was able to solve this by doing two things. Note that one alone might be sufficient.

First, explicitly tell Docker to use ZFS as filesystem, by writing `{"storage-driver": "zfs"}` in the file `/etc/docker/daemon.json`. (If the file exists in your disk, then just add the storage-driver key)

Second, create the following systemd unit in the file `/etc/systemd/system/docker-wait-zfs.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Wait for ZFS before starting Docker
RequiredBy=docker.service
Before=docker.service
Requires=zfs.target
After=zfs.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/true
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then execute:

```
systemctl enable docker-wait-zfs.service
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer here did not work for me after a recent update. It seems you cannot have "{"storage-driver": "zfs"}" in your "/etc/docker/daemon.json" anymore,  unless the root drive is using ZFS. This was not applicable to me, since I was just mapping folders to my containers which happen to reside on ZFS.

To fix this, the following worked:

1. sudo systemctl edit docker.service
2. Add the following contents:

   `After=zfs-mount.service
   Requires=zfs-mount.service
   Wants=zfs-mount.service
   BindsTo=zfs-mount.service`

The answer [here](https://serverfault.com/a/725684), contains explanation for what each line does.